# how to run ROS2 RIVZ in docker on macos

Tags: ros2, rviz

i try to run rviz in docker on macos & XQuartz.
for this, i'll use devcontainers and docker but i get this error :

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Unable to create glx context
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
[ERROR] [1691576707.009589769] [rviz2]: Failed to create an OpenGL context. BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
[ERROR] [1691576707.009946561] [rviz2]: RenderingAPIException: Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 60)
[ERROR] [1691576707.010118905] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 60)
[ERROR] [1691576707.023287294] [rviz2]: Failed to create an OpenGL context. BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
[ERROR] [1691576707.023363621] [rviz2]: RenderingAPIException: Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 60)
[ERROR] [1691576707.023570158] [rviz2]: rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: RenderingAPIException: Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 60)
[ERROR] [1691576707.037757023] [rviz2]: Failed to create an OpenGL context. BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
[ERROR] [1691576707.037868863] [rviz2]: RenderingAPIException: Unable to create a suitable GLXContext in GLXContext::GLXContext at ./.obj-x86_64-linux-gnu/ogre-v1.12.1-prefix/src/ogre-v1.12.1/RenderSystems/GLSupport/src/GLX/OgreGLXContext.cpp (line 60)
```

my devcontainers.json file is like this :

```
{
    "name": "ROS 2 Development Container",
    "privileged": true,
    "remoteUser": "USERNAME",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile",
        "args": {
            "USERNAME": "USERNAME"
        }
    },
    "workspaceFolder": "/home/ws",
    "workspaceMount": "source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/home/ws/src,type=bind",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions":[
                "ms-vscode.cpptools",
                "ms-vscode.cpptools-themes",
                "twxs.cmake",
                "donjayamanne.python-extension-pack",
                "eamodio.gitlens",
                "ms-iot.vscode-ros"
            ]
        }
    },
    "containerEnv": {
        "DISPLAY": "host.docker:0",
        "ROS_AUTOMATIC_DISCOVERY_RANGE": "LOCALHOST",
        "ROS_DOMAIN_ID": "42"
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--net=host",
        "-e", "DISPLAY=${env:DISPLAY}"
    ],
    "mounts": [
        "source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,type=bind,consistency=cached",
        "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/../cache/IRON/build,target=/home/ws/build,type=bind",
        "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/../cache/IRON/install,target=/home/ws/install,type=bind",
        "source=${localWorkspaceFolder}/../cache/IRON/log,target=/home/ws/log,type=bind"
    ],
    "postCreateCommand": "sudo rosdep update && sudo rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y && sudo chown -R USERNAME /home/ws/"
}
```

and my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ros:iron
ARG USERNAME=USERNAME
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
#
# [Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting.
&& apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y sudo \
&& echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
&& chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
ENV SHELL /bin/bash

# ********************************************************
# * Anything else you want to do like clean up goes here *
# ********************************************************

# [Optional] Set the default user. Omit if you want to keep the default as root.
USER $USERNAME
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

can you help me to solve my problem
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The libgl error suggests to me that this is a problem with displaying the UI within a container, rather than a problem with RViz, docker, etc. Searching for information about your libgl error provides two suggestions:

- There might be a missing binary, [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=262084) arch linux help thread suggests making sure `lib32-nvidia-utils` is installed. That missing binary suggests to me that you need to be building off of a container with better UI support: since you're using `ros:iron`, which is only installing the `ros_base` metapackage, you aren't using a container UI packages installed.
- There might be an environment variable you should set; for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69049171/how-to-fix-libgl-error-in-qt5-qml-gui-launched-from-docker-on-linux) stack overflow post suggests setting `QT_QUICK_BACKEND=software` while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831052/how-do-i-run-opengl-programs-using-wsl-ubuntu-20-04) one suggests setting `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`.

So I would recommend first ensuring that you're explicitly installing the ros desktop packages in your container, and then trying alternative environment variables to coax libgl into behaving within the container.